# How to use Azure Diagnostics with Python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013, azure-diagnostics

I have created a python project (console app) using Visual Studio 2013 and have installed the following:
1) Microsoft Azure SDK for Python 3.4 - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/python-how-to-install/
2) Python Tools for Visual Studio - https://pytools.codeplex.com/

I am successful in accessing Azure Storage (Blob & Queue) using Python. However, I am not able to use Azure Diagnostics for logging messages.

Is there a way I can use Azure Diagnostics with Python source code?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Diagnostics can collect the following types of telemetry:

> - IIS Logs
> - Azure Diagnostic infrastructure logs
> - IIS Failed Request logs
> - Windows Event logs
> - Performance counters
> - Crash dumps
> - Custom error logs
> - .NET EventSource
> - Manifest based ETW

Using Python, however, all of the above may not be possible. But, "azure-storage-logging" provides functionality to send output from the standard Python logging APIs to Microsoft Azure Storage (Table/Queue).

### Dependencies

azure 0.9 or newer

### Installation

Install the package via pip:

*pip install azure-storage-logging*

### Usage

```
    LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'formatters': {
            'simple': {
                'format': '%(asctime)s %(message)s',
            },
            'verbose': {
                'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(hostname)s %(process)d %(message)s',
            },
            # this is the same as the default, so you can skip configuring it
            'partition_key': {
                'format': '%(asctime)s',
                'datefmt': '%Y%m%d%H%M',
            },
            # this is the same as the default, so you can skip configuring it
            'row_key': {
                'format': '%(asctime)s%(msecs)03d-%(hostname)s-%(process)d-%(rowno)02d',
                'datefmt': '%Y%m%d%H%M%S',
            },
        },
        'handlers': {
            'file': {
                'account_name': 'mystorageaccountname',
                'account_key': 'mystorageaccountkey',
                'protocol': 'https',
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'azure_storage_logging.handlers.BlobStorageTimedRotatingFileHandler',
                'formatter': 'verbose',
                'filename': 'example.log',
                'when': 'D',
                'interval': 1,
                'container': 'logs-%(hostname)s',
                'zip_compression': False,
            },
            'queue': {
                'account_name': 'mystorageaccountname',
                'account_key': 'mystorageaccountkey',
                'protocol': 'https',
                'queue': 'logs',
                'level': 'CRITICAL',
                'class': 'azure_storage_logging.handlers.QueueStorageHandler',
                'formatter': 'verbose',
            },
            'table': {
                'account_name': 'mystorageaccountname',
                'account_key': 'mystorageaccountkey',
                'protocol': 'https',
                'table': 'logs',
                'level': 'INFO',
                'class': 'azure_storage_logging.handlers.TableStorageHandler',
                'formatter': 'simple',
                'batch_size': 20,
                'extra_properties': ['%(hostname)s', '%(levelname)s'],
                'partition_key_formatter': 'cfg://formatters.partition_key',
                'row_key_formatter': 'cfg://formatters.row_key',
            },
        },
        'loggers': {
            'example': {
                'handlers': ['file', 'queue', 'table'],
                'level': 'DEBUG',
            },
        }
    }

    import logging
    from logging.config import dictConfig

    dictConfig(LOGGING)
    logger = logging.getLogger('example')
    logger.debug('debug message')
    logger.info('info message')
    logger.warning('warning message')
    logger.error('error message')
    logger.critical('critical message')
```

Source: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure-storage-logging/